Isothermal Titration Calorimetry (ITC) to Determine the Critical Micelle Concentration (CMC) of Surfactans
Lately I found a paper from Smith et al. (2022), where isothermal titration calorimetry (ITC) was used to determine the critical micelle concentration (CMC) of different surfactants. However, as I am new to the method of ITC analysis I had some problems following the results.
The experimental approach is straight foward, by continously adding different surfactants to water during the ITC measurements, the CMC is to be determined.

While it is clear to me how to determine the CMC when obtaining a sigmoidal curve, as the one shown above, by determining the inflection point, I do not understand how to do so in the case shown below.
How is the CMC respectively the inflection point defined/determined in this case? Is there a specific fitting function available for this? If yes how is it defined?

Thank you in advance!
Images obtained from: Smith et al., 2002, CMC determination using isothermal titration calorimetry for five industrially significant non-ionic surfactants, Colloids and Surfaces B: Biointerfaces 211 (2022) 112320.

You are right, the second curve is dubious. Authors say they use the first derivative. I tried to take the first and second derivative of the second curve...nothing clear. Try writing to the author (corresponding author) or search better papers.

Thank you for replying, yes, I did the same thing and determined the derivatives, but not sure how this is supposed to help to find a specific point on the curve, which can be selected as CMC. I have been looking for other papers but up to now, I have not found any where it becomes clear how to handle such a curve. Contacting the author might be the easiest thing to do...

Long time ago, someone advised me that don't trust any paper until and unless we read 11-12 papers. People make mistakes in papers or forget to write more details, and it is not uncommon being unable to reproduce data.
